# App that automatically records/recognizes speech and compiles in a list?

Tags: note-taking, speech-recognition

I'm a business owner and am constantly pulled in different directions.  To keep track of what I do all day, I use a system where I use DROPVOX to record what I am doing, and a virtual assistant to transcribe this into a google spreadsheet.

This dropvox method works great because from my point of view, the only thing I need to do is hit the dropvox button, say what I am doing, and then I am done.  I don't need to open up a spreadsheet on my phone or walk across a room to type something in.

Instead of paying a virtual assistant to transcribe daily, I want to see if there is an app that can transcribe and automatically send it to a location where it will be compiled.

One app that I found that was very close to this was VDictation.  This app will transcribe what I say.  From here, I can send it as a text to a google voice account that I have...(This is good because I can have a running list).  However, with this app, I need to select that I want to send a text and then input the phone number.  I want to get rid of these steps and simply know that I have to just click the voice memo button and it will be uploaded to a list.

Any ideas?  Questions to understand what I'm talking about?  Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Google Docs just recently added microphone support that can transcribe for you. There are also voice commands available to create lists and format documents. Unfortunately, there's no send-to-a-location feature that you're looking for.